# Having an issue getting convertTo-Json to return required format

Tags: json, powershell

I have an API that is expecting the the JSON to be format.  I can't seem to get the array brackets correct.

As you will see in the expected format there is a bracketed [] section for contacts.  My code is missing the brackets.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

***Here is the expected format:***

```
{        
    "version": 0,
    "createDate": "",
    "updateDate": "",
    "enabled": true,
    "name": "1157 - Company X (X57)",
    "contacts": 
    [
        { 
            "notifications": {
                "receipt": true,
                "recency": false,
                "data": false,
                "failure": true
                },
                "email": "BettrAEs@mycompany.com",
                "firstName": "CCC",
                "lastName": "AE",
                "company": "My Company"
        }
    ]
}
```

***Here is my code and output:***

```
$jinfo = [pscustomobject]@{
    version    = 0
    createDate = ''
    updateDate = ''
    enabled    = $true
    name       = '1157 - Company X (X57)'
    contacts = @{
        notifications = [pscustomobject]@{
            receipt = $true
            recency = $false
            data    = $false
            failure = $true
        }
        email       = 'BettrAEs@mycompany.com'
        firstName   = 'CCC'
        lastName    = 'AE'
        company     = 'My Company'
    }
}|convertTo-Json
$jinfo
**ouput**
{
    "version":  0,
    "createDate":  "",
    "updateDate":  "",
    "enabled":  true,
    "name":  "1157 - Company X (X57)",
    "contacts":  {
                     "email":  "BettrAEs@mycompany.com",
                     "notifications":  {
                                      "receipt":  true,
                                      "recency":  false,
                                      "data":  false,
                                      "failure":  true
                                  },
                     "firstName":  "CCC",
                     "company":  "My Company",
                     "lastName":  "AE"
                 }
}
```

Comment: `[]` are for lists/arrays - replace `contacts = @{ ... }` with `contacts = @(@{ ... })`

Comment: Using this [ConvertTo-Expression](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression) cmdlet: `'{ "version": 0,  "createDate": "", ... } | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Expression` which will reveal the specific part as: `contacts = ,[pscustomobject]@{ ...` (use an [Comma Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) in front of the `[pscustomobject]`)